# Invalid broken image path

Tags: error-message, image

I’ve converted an old site with 15+ years of posts over to Craft from WP. There were a lot of missing images, I’ve handled this with the broken image path setting in the config/general.php.

However, I’m getting numerous missing image errors in the PHP log and each one is accompanied by the following error:

```
yii\base\InvalidConfigException: Invalid broken image path: /assets/ui/default/image_404.svg in /home/customer/www/[ SITE ]/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/AppController.php:626
```

That path (/assets/ui/default/image_404.svg) is correct, the image is there.

I have a couple of ideas:

1. It needs to be an absolute path
2. Maybe an SVG is no good and it needs to be a PNG/WebP

Can anyone suggest anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVGs are fine, but the `brokenImagePath` needs to be an absolute file path.

The setting supports [aliases](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#aliases), so if your `@webroot` alias is properly configured it could be set to

```
'brokenImagePath' => '@webroot/assets/ui/default/image_404.svg',
```

See [the official docs on the `brokenImagePath`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#brokenimagepath) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was it :)